# Tomatillo leaf greying

Tags: tomatillos

[image]I have a tomatillo plant that has leaf browning and am unable to determine likely cause: nutrient, blight, water issue or all the above?I have a pic but unclear how to post herein

Comment: Look under the leaves for bugs.